# Como agregar una condicional al renderizar un array?

Tags: reactjs

Buenas estoy tratando de renderizar un listado de notas segun si se encuentran activas o no. Lo que hice fue agregar un boton para archivar que cuando se hace click en ese boton le cambia el estado a 0. Donde 0 es para desactivado y 1 para activo. Yo en mi lista quiero mostrar solo los elementos con un estado == 1 o !=0.

Para ello utiliza .map para renderizar mi array pero nose como y donde introducir una condicional para mostrar solo los elementos activos.

```
return (
    <div>
        {notes.map(note =>(
            <Card key={note.id} style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                
                <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{note.title}</Card.Title>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} style={{float:"right", padding:"5px" }} onClick={() => deleteNoteHandler(note.id)}/>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPencil} style={{float:"right", padding:"5px"}} onClick={() => editNoteHandler(note.id)}/>
                <Card.Text>
                    {note.description}
                </Card.Text>
               
                </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        ))}
        {modal.isLoading && <ModalDelete onDialog={confirmDelete} message={modal.message}/>}
    </div>
  )
```

El campo que contiene el estado de mis notas es note.active, entonces sería algo como renderizar todos los elementos que note.activa !== 0.

Comment: `notes.map(note =>{ return note.activa != 0 ? (// tu Card) : null })`

Comment: se puede hacer un return dentro de otro return? @JaimeMenéndez

Comment: El return ese es para el callback del map, no tiene que ver nada con el return de tu componente.

Comment: tecnicamente deberias hacerlo fuera en un hooks ya que estas ensuciando la view!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes apoyarte del operador lógico AND(&&) realizando la validación antes de mostrar el componente deseado, de tal forma que si no se cumple la condición no se mostrara nada.

```
{notes.map(note =>(

     note.activa != 0 &&

            <Card key={note.id} style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                
                <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{note.title}</Card.Title>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} style={{float:"right", padding:"5px" }} onClick={() => deleteNoteHandler(note.id)}/>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPencil} style={{float:"right", padding:"5px"}} onClick={() => editNoteHandler(note.id)}/>
                <Card.Text>
                    {note.description}
                </Card.Text>
               
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
 ))}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Otra posibilidad es usar [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). El código se vería algo así. Y recuerda que puedes concatenar las llamadas dado que filter devuelve un nuevo arreglo que solo contiene los elementos que cumplen la condición.

```
return (
  <div>
    { 
      notes.filter(note => note.active === 1)
        .map(note => (
          <Card key={note.id}>
              <Card.Body>
                
              </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        )
      )
    }
  </div>
);
```